# Is there any function's result value must be used specifier In Typescript?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to specify that the function's return value must be used using typescript.
There is an attribute [[nodiscard]] in c++. Is there any similar attribute in Typescript?

Example:

```js
function setSomeFields(someThing: MyClass) {
    const other = new MyClass();
    other.value = someThing.value;
    //...
    return other;
}
//...
// wanted: error or warning
setSomeFields(myClass);

// correct
const newMyClass = setSomeFields(myClass);
```

Comment: That's not a `typescript` topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/issues/741) on `eslint` to for a `no-unused-return-value` rule that would give you the warning you want but a rule like that was never included. For now, the [SonarJS](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs) plugin for `eslint` does seem to have such a [rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs/blob/master/docs/rules/no-ignored-return.md).